# Troubleshooting in loading files in R

Tags: r

I'm brand new learner programming "R'.but faced problem in loading files:

I used this code :

```
getwd()
load("genData.RData")
genData
```

Output shows:
Console:

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/User/Documents"
> load("genData.Rdata")
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'genData.Rdata', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
> genData
Error: object 'genData' not found
```

Is there any kind sould to unravel the problem??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message means that there is no file `genData.Rdata` in the currect directory, which is `"C:/Users/User/Documents"`

Comment: Try specifying the full path to the file, assuming it actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because R cannot find the file in the current working directory (the working directory is the one you see with the command getwd()). This can either be because your file is in another directory (if so, try specifying the full path, or change working directory to the one where the file is located with setwd()) or because the name of the file is wrong (check syntax).
To see if the file is in the current working directory, you can also do

```
list.files(pattern='*.Rdata')
```

This prints out in the R console all the files contained in the current working directory which have an .Rdata extension.
Hope this helps